# Flex: How to listen to event in ItemRenderer

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I try to make have an EventListener in ItemRenderer but its not working. How to listen to an event inside an ItemRenderer?

----In MainHomeView.mxml----

```
<fx:Metadata>
    [Event(name="myEvent", type="flash.events.Event")]
</fx:Metadata>

protected function btnAdd_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {       
    var eventObject:Event = new Event("myEvent", true, true);
    dispatchEvent(eventObject);       
}
```

----In UserRenderer.mxml (ItemRenderer)---

```
protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void{ //run in CreationComplete
       addEventListener("myEvent", onHandleEvent);
      }

 protected function onHandleEvent():void  {
        trace("Event received");
      }
```

Comment: The itemrenderer is not in the event propagation path from the Button you have the click handler on. You could try `list.dispatchEvent(eventObject)`, but I don't think that will work either. Why don't you manipulate the dataprovider instead of this?

Comment: @SamDeHaan so you are saying there is no way to have a listener in itemRenderer, even with custom event? hmmm too bad

Comment: It's possible, but events only propagate "up" from the dispatcher. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_08.html You would need to find a way to dispatch the event "below" the itemrenderers, which would be difficult.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use some form of global (static) eventdispatcher, which the itemrenderers and the main class would have a reference to. I haven't done it myself, but it should work.

Comment: @SamDeHaan event propagation, but the button is a separate part of the itemRenderer parent container (list), will event propagation reach the button? I need to do some research in Global static eventdispatcher

Comment: The idea is that you have an object that dispatches events that is "below" everything. It's not perfect for all situations, but it can be effective. I'll be off SO for the rest of the night, if you haven't gotten this to work tomorrow I'll do my best to assist further.

Comment: @SamDeHaan thanks f your suggestion about Static EventDispatcher, I have google and found the solution in: http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/building_a_stat.html. But by using this method, each item in the ItemRenderer will received an event, so if you have 100 items (in your ItemRenderer) you will rec'd 100 events.

Comment: What are you trying to do? There's probably a better pattern.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I'm trying to use a button to change the state inside the itemRenderer and the state of the parent as well. The button has to be in the parent level.

Comment: There's obviously more to it than that, since you are only wanting to change the state in _one_ renderer. My first instinct would be to say you should simply set a property on the data object the renderer is rendering, but there are probably other ways to handl this based on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship thanks, i will try to find another way to handle it. but in also found a solution in this link:gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/building_a_stat.html. Hope that will help someone as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have google and found the solution in [gskinner](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/07/building_a_stat.html). But by using this method, each item in the ItemRenderer will received an event, so if you have 100 items (in your ItemRenderer) you will rec'd 100 events.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late, but according to your sample, your ItemRenderer is listening to itself - which is why you'll never get the event. And as for bubbling, remember in both the target and capture phase, things start from the stage and work its way up to dispatching target, then back down again. Since your renderer is a child of the list, it will never receive this event.

If you want the IR to get the event from the list, you'll need a reference to the list - usually **owner**. In which case, this is owner.addEventListener(). You can also look at the **ListData** that is assigned to each renderer, and in that composite object is a reference to the list.

Straight from the documentation:

> The event target serves as the focal point for how events flow through the display list hierarchy. When an event such as a mouse click or a keypress occurs, Flash Player or the AIR application dispatches an event object into the **event flow from the root** of the display list. The event object then makes its way through the display list until it reaches the event target, at which point it begins its return trip through the display list. This round-trip journey to the event target is conceptually divided into three phases: the capture phase comprises the journey from the root to the last node before the event target's node, the target phase comprises only the event target node, and the bubbling phase comprises any subsequent nodes encountered on the return trip to the root of the display list

You'll need to be a little careful with this, since the ItemRenderer is part of a ClassFactory creation method **each** renderer will be assigned this listener - this may or may not be what you want.

Comment: i have found out that listening to event in IR is not a good thing and i had used another way to get around my problem. thanks